# SSIS 14 Issue - Enough disk

Tags: ssis, buffer, disk

I was running my SSIS package in order to make some transformations in Staging Area when I got the following error:

```
Error: The buffer manager cannot extend the 
file "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\3\DTS{CFB0A22A-23C4-4111-BE80-84643E8E579E}.tmp" to length 1046308 bytes.  
There was insufficient disk space.
```

This error happens in a Lookup Object before the OLE DB Destination.

I'm not the technical guy here but I need to load my DW util next week! What can I do in this situation? Can I put SSIS point to another drive in my machine? How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is pointing to your TEMP folder. Set the TEMP path to a different drive and directory and reboot your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is addressed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/912ee1eb-8d95-4cc6-9844-cb7f56d36515/ssis-job-failure?forum=sqlintegrationservices), but in summary the temporary files are created in directory specified by BufferTempStoragePath property of data flow task. By default it uses user's temporary files folder (%TEMP%), but can be overridden for each data flow task. There is a problem with this path, and data flow can't create temporary files there. Check that the path is correct, you have permissions to write to this path, and there is enough free space during package execution.